# Excel Conditional formatting from one to many

Tags: excel, one-to-many, conditional-formatting

There are 3 sheets in my workbook
A! Squad Names and base details

## [ Squad # | Engaged (YES|NO) | Squad Name | Base |  ]

Squad Name is highlighted when they are Engaged

B! Squad Mission(s)

## [ MOS # | Squad | MOS Name | MOS Desc |  ]

C! Required Data-Validation Lists for ease in Search of A!

I understand how to conditionally format of column C when column B has a specific value.
I want to Highlight the MOS Name(s) on page B! associated with specific squad names when the squad is marked as Engaged on A!.
Squad names are associated with from 5 to 17 MOS codes.

Answer (score 1):

You would have to use `VLOOKUP`. As suggested into the [VLOOKUP Microsoft documentation](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/VLOOKUP-function-0BBC8083-26FE-4963-8AB8-93A18AD188A1), `VLOOKUP` is one of the lookup and reference functions, when you need to find things in a table or a range by row.

Here is how that works:

```
=VLOOKUP(Value you want to look up, range where you want to lookup the value, the column number in the range containing the return value, Exact Match or Approximate Match – indicated as 0/FALSE or 1/TRUE)
```

- Value you want to look up: The cell with the MOS name to search
- Range where you want to lookup the value: From the top 1st column to the bottom 4th column of your table into the sheet "A! Squad Names and base details", e.g.: `A1:D44` if there is 44 rows.
- The column number in the range containing the return value: 2 as this is where we can know if this is yes or no

Then you put the `VLOOKUP` result into your conditional formatting. Based on [Microsoft Documentation Use formulas with conditional formatting](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Use-formulas-with-conditional-formatting-FED60DFA-1D3F-4E13-9ECB-F1951FF89D7F), here is the step how to dot it:

1. Select cells you want to apply the format on.
2. Then, click Home > Conditional Formatting > New Rule.
3. In the New Formatting Rule dialog box, click Use a formula to determine which cells to format.
4. Under Format values where this formula is true, type the formula: `=VLOOKUP(C1,'A! Squad Names and base details'!A1:D44,2,FALSE) = "YES"`
5. Click Format and decide your preferences
6. Click OK until the dialog boxes are closed.

The formatting is applied to the column selected

Hope it will help you.